# Get rid of duplicate entries in autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I am having difficulty getting rid of duplicate entries which are showing up in autocomplete.
The autocomplete is generated dynamically from a database.

This is the code which is being used for the autocomplete in the control:

```
 public ActionResult AutoCompletefootball()
    {
        var db = new footEntities();
        string selection = this.Request.Params["term"].ToString();
        return Json(db.football.Where(a => a.player.Name.StartsWith(selection)).Select(Adds => a.Player.Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

All advice welcome

Comment: So you might say you're looking for `.Distinct()` suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your return statement (where you use LINQ), add DISTINCT clause.

Answer (score 0):

.Distinct() will eliminate duplicates, but consider that duplicates are appearing because there are many players with the same name, so they are not really duplicate people

Comment: Just dummy data – well spotted.